# LINQ Using ROW_NUMBER() function?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, sql-server-2012

I have a table that shows a list of sync's from our mobile users back to our database. This means that each user could have thousands of sync records.

I have written a query that uses the `ROW_NUMBER()` function to pull the most recent sync for every user and only active users, as I don't want to see sync'd data from terminated employees. (i.e. User A sync'd yesterday at noon, User A sync'd today at noon but I only want to see the sync from today).

```
SELECT * FROM 
  ( 
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [SerialNumber] ORDER BY SyncDate DESC )as RN
    FROM [TSCH].[dbo].[SYNCREPORT]
    ) as T
    Where RN = 1 and WorkerStatus = 'ACTIVE' and SerialNumber = ######;
```

What would the best approach for writing this using LINQ in c# for my .net web application? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can't you just tell LINQ to call a stored procedure that does exactly that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could be something like this

```
var result=yourtable.OrderBy(x=>x.SyncDate).GroupBy(x=>x.SerialNumber)
       .Where(x=>x.WorkerStatus=="Active" && x.SerialNumber=="####")
       .Select(g => new {g, count= g.Count()})
       .SelectMany(t => t.g.Select(b => b)
       .Zip(Enumerable.Range(1,t.count), (c,i) => new {c.value1, c,value2, rn = i}));
```